# Git-tf unable to find required JAR

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I'm trying to setup git-tf bridge on my windows work station. When I try to execute one of the commands it always shows message:

Unable to find a required JAR: C:\my\path\to\git-tf/lib/com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc-*jar does not exist.

The problem is that slash changes in the middle of the path from \ is changed to /.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that's the problem?  Are there some files matching that path wildcard?  How did you uncompress the zip file?

Comment: Which command did you use?

Comment: Actually turned out that if Im using "git tf" commands error occurs but if I use "git-tf" everything is fine.

Comment: But it should work with `git tf`. I had it working until I reinstalled git. Now I get the same error. Any new insights?

Comment: I installed git-tf the other day and git tf never worked. Did you work this out?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I'm assuming you use the Git Bash.

You'll need to edit your `git-tf` bash script and change the line

```
MINGW32_NT*)
```

to

```
MINGW*)
```

because for you, `uname -s` will probably spit out “MINGW64_NT”.

Comment: Exactly the issue, exactly the solution - much obliged.

Comment: Had the same issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thx

Comment: This file exists under C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Git-TF\Tools\git-tf-2.0.3.20131219\git-tf

Comment: Just stumbled upon the very same issue. Solution works perfectly. Make sure it is the git-tf file and not the cmd file.

Answer (score 24):

Try using "git-tf" instead of "git tf".  That got me past the issue on Windows (using PowerShell or just the vanilla command prompt).

Answer (score 0):

> For me the case is actually that the jar file is not available.

Check first if a chocolatey installation would bring that jar in the installed path, as in [this issue](https://gittf.codeplex.com/workitem/147).

```
choco install git-tf 
# or
choco upgrade git-tf -version 2.0.3.20131219
```

You should see:

```
Contents of Git-TF\lib:
com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc-2.0.3.20131219.jar
com.microsoft.gittf.core-2.0.3.20131219.jar
com.microsoft.tfs.sdk-12.0.0.jar
org.eclipse.jgit-3.1.0.201310021548-r.jar
```

The official archive [`git-tf-2.0.3.20131219.zip`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/E/2/AE23B059-5727-445B-91CC-15B7A078A7F4/git-tf-2.0.3.20131219.zip) has the expected jars.

Comment: I apologize, didn't mention before. I cannot go with choclatey option. I've directly downloaded from Microsoft's download page...

Comment: @deostroll ant the content of the archive you downloaded is not the same as the one I mention in the answer?

Comment: @deostroll Because I just downloaded http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/E/2/AE23B059-5727-445B-91CC-15B7A078A7F4/git-tf-2.0.3.20131219.zip (from the page https://gittf.codeplex.com/releases/view/116074), and I do have those jars.

Comment: Weird thing to notice, but the zip on my desktop didn't have the files, but the zip downloaded in our shared software directory has them. Eludes me as to how this happened...

Answer (score 0):

If the script exists, it warns that it could not be found, you should try using "git-tf" instead of "git tf". I worked well.