# git tf clone can't to find JAR "com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc"

Tags: git, powershell, git-tf

I'm getting this error when running the command below using **powershell**

```
git tf clone http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/mycollectionname $/myprojectname

**error:**
*Unable to find a required JAR: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Git-TF\Tools\git-tf-2.0.3.20131219/lib/com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc-*.jar does not exist*

the file exists on folder path:
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Git-TF\Tools\git-tf-2.0.3.20131219\lib
```

but the on error message it shows that the file is searched on

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Git-TF\Tools\git-tf-2.0.3.20131219**/**lib**/**
```

with `"/"` instead if `"\"`

I saw similar question and answers on this link:
[Git-tf unable to find required JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915987/git-tf-unable-to-find-required-jar)

BUT, it is not solving my issue.

can anyone assist on this?

thanks.

Comment: Are you using that Bash command prompt or the regular Windows command prompt?

Comment: windows powershell. tried to use also git bash command with the workaround suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915987/git-tf-unable-to-find-required-jar didnt help.

Comment: Git-tf hasn't been updated in 7 years. Most people on Windows use [git tfs](http://git-tfs.com/). Some people have posted comments on chocolatey.org about issues in general with using this tool: https://chocolatey.org/packages/Git-TF

Comment: And a note from Microsoft that git-tf has reached end-of-life: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gittf

Comment: @Greg Burghardt git-tfs didn't work for us, but git-tf did. And git-tf is still available from official Microsoft sources.